# string like "2016-06-06" to Date object in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am new to swift 3, the way I found is

```
extension Date
{
    init(dateString:String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
        let d = dateStringFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
        self(timeInterval:0, since:d)
    }
}`
```

in self(timeInterval:0, since:d)

raise error Cannot call value of non-function type 'Date'

also I doesn't see this error before. Anyone please help me and explain it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:
 `self.init(timeInterval:0, since:d)`

Comment: in swift we do Object() instead of Object.init()? why we need self.init() here instead of self ()

Answer (score 2):

The result `dateStringFormatter.date(from: dateString)!` is a `Date`, you have no need to call another initializer in such cases for struts.

```
extension Date
{
    init(dateString:String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
        self = dateStringFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    }
}
print(Date(dateString: "2016-09-27")) //->2016-09-26 15:00:00 +0000
```

I'm not sure using user's default TimeZone is what you intend.